# How to create stackoverflow type buttons?

Tags: button, extjs4

I would like to know how to create stack overflow type buttons (buttons like in image below)? Is it possible to create buttons like this using ExtJS?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone made an extension for that awhile ago.

It is not *exactly* like SO buttons but you could play around with the CSS a bit and possibly add a few overrides to get it 100%.

I think the fourth example (forceSelection: false) is probably the most similar. Just hide the field box and change the close icon and you're basically there.

[Here](http://kveeiv.github.com/extjs-boxselect/examples/boxselect.html) are the examples.

And [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox) is the thread.